# Java: Splitting string equation into numbers and operators

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string, split

I am trying to split a string equation into two arrays: numbers and operators.

```
String expr = "3/20.0";

String[] numbers = expr.split("[+-/\\*]");
String[] operators = expr.split("[^+-/\\*]+");

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(operators));
```

But my code prints out: `[3, 20, 0] [, /, .]`

But I'm trying to get `[3, 20.0] [, /]`

I am not sure why the comma is in front of the operators array, but mainly I just want 20.0 to be one element in the numbers array and keep decimal points out of my operators array.

Comment: fwiw: `+-/` in the character class doesn't mean "+ or - or /" it means any character _between_ + and /.  Which in ASCII is the set "+,-./".  (Which is why it matches the ".") If you want to put a - in a character class, put it at the end.

Answer (score 1):

The comma's are just showing you the element partition.
This `[,` means the first  element is blank.

Try these *raw* regex

For numbers, split on `[^\d.]+`
For operators, split on `[\d.]+`

And, I don't know if Java split can delete empty elements, but you'd want to
do a check post process if you can.

---

Split Notes -
`[\d.]+` is a class that generally matches numbers, ie. 'dd.dd'  ( *leaves operators* )
`[^\d.]+` is the *inverse* where it matches operators ( *leaves numbers* )

Comment: Wow, this works! Can you explain to me what those each mean?